# How do you write a binary literal in ruby?

Tags: ruby, binary

Most languages (Ruby included) allow number literals to be written in at least three bases: decimal, octal and hexadecimal. Numbers in decimal base is the usual thing and are written as (most) people naturally write numbers, 96 is written as `96`. Numbers prefixed by a zero are usually interpreted as octal based: 96 would be written as `0140`. Hexadecimal based numbers are usually prefixed by `0x`: 96 would be written as `0x60`.

The question is: can I write numbers as binary literals in Ruby? How?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

use 0b prefix

```
>> 0b100
=> 4
```

Answer (score 17):

and you can do:

```
>> easy_to_read_binary = 0b1110_0000_0000_0000
=> 57344
>> easy_to_read_binary.to_s(10)
=> "57344"
```

Answer (score 15):

For literals, the prefix is 0b. So

```
0b100 #=> 4
```

Be aware that the same exists to format strings:

```
"%b" % 4 #=> "100"
```

Answer (score 8):

From [this manual](http://docs.huihoo.com/ruby/ruby-man-1.4/syntax.html#numeric)

```
0b01011
```

binary integer