# Ruby: why is there a letter in this binary?

Tags: ruby, binary

I'm trying to make sense of some code samples. I get expressions like this...

```
exit_status |= 0b0010
exit_status |= 0b0001
```

I go here to translate the binary: http://home.paulschou.net/tools/xlate/

and get that `0b0010` is `2` and `0b0001` is `1`

I understand that `0010` is `2` and that `0001` is 1, my question is... why is there kinda like a `0b` prefix and what does it mean or how does it work?

Comment: It's meant to indicate the base. Different digits can mean different numbers. 10 stands for 10 in base 10, 2 in base 2 and 16 in base 16.

Answer (score 3):

[`0b` is simply an indication of a binary literal.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101461/how-do-you-write-a-binary-literal-in-ruby?rq=1) Otherwise the number would not be interpreted as base 2.

More: http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/language.html#UC

Answer (score 3):

The `0b` is a literal, designating the value as a number in binary representation. This is just like `0x` in `0xFF4ABD` designates it as a hexadecimal number.

This is due to the fact that numbers can be expressed in multiple systems. There exist multiple systems of how numbers can be represented, like the decimal number system `1234`, or the Roman number system `MCXIVII`. Binary and hexadecimal numbers are just two more of these systems.

NOTE: If you were to type `1234`, Ruby would interpret it as a decimal number. If you were to type it as `01234`, for example, if you want to have multiple numbers formatted in unison (all numbers the same lengt), it would be interpreted as an octal number!

Answer (score 2):

- 0b: prefix binary number; example: 0b011 (3 decimal)
- 0: prefix octal number; example: 010 (8 decimal)
- 0x: prefix hexadecimal number; example: 0x10 (16 decimal)

Answer (score 1):

`0b` is the prefix which says to interpret the following numbers as binary digits, like the `0x` prefix says that the following digits are hexadecimal, as in eg, `0xffff`. For more, see [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Numerics).